# PHP error when creating image using imagecreatetruecolor

Tags: php, html, image, php-7

I got a simple **HTML** that calls a image generated from a PHP file but the image is not being displayed. The HTML part is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
    <img src="imgcaptcha.php"/>
</body>

</html>
```

**imgcaptcha.php** is:

```
<?php
//error_reporting(E_ALL);
//header('Content-Type: image/png');

//Generates rando string
function geraStringAleatoria($length = 10) {
    $charSet = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $stringAleatoria = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $stringAleatoria .= $charSet[rand(0, strlen($charSet) - 1)];
    }
    return $stringAleatoria;
}
//Generate the captcha image
function geraImagemCaptcha($text = 'good'){
    // Set the content-type
    $width  = 200;
    $height = 30;
    // Create the image
    $im = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height) or die('display nao instalado');;

    // Create some colors
    $white  = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
    $grey   = imagecolorallocate($im, 128, 128, 128);
    $black  = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
    imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, $width-1, $height-1, $white);

    //ADD NOISE - DRAW background squares
    $square_count = 6;
    for($i = 0; $i < $square_count; $i++){
        $cx = rand(0,$width);
        $cy = (int)rand(0, $width/2);
        $h  = $cy + (int)rand(0, $height/5);
        $w  = $cx + (int)rand($width/3, $width);
        imagefilledrectangle($im, $cx, $cy, $w, $h, $white);
    }

    //ADD NOISE - DRAW ELLIPSES
    $ellipse_count = 5;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $ellipse_count; $i++) {
      $cx = (int)rand(-1*($width/2), $width + ($width/2));
      $cy = (int)rand(-1*($height/2), $height + ($height/2));
      $h  = (int)rand($height/2, 2*$height);
      $w  = (int)rand($width/2, 2*$width);
      imageellipse($im, $cx, $cy, $w, $h, $grey);
    }

    // Replace path by your own font path
    $font = 'flushout.ttf';

    // Add some shadow to the text
    imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 11, 21, $grey, $font, $text);

    // Add the text
    imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 10, 20, $black, $font, $text);

    // Using imagepng() results in clearer text compared with imagejpeg()
    imagepng($im);

    imagedestroy($im);

}
geraImagemCaptcha(geraStringAleatoria());
?>
```

I'm using **PHP 7** 
Tried already commenting out `header();` call and add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` but no error message was displayed. Tried also many other different font.ttf files according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24115545/2414842), also didn't worked, so I guess that the problem is in another part of the code rather than the font because I tried many sites and also some other .ttf files I got from other programs installed. The problem is happening in both all browsers I tested. What could be missing in the code? Btw, I got this generate captcha image from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21750106/2414842).

Comment: Did you try creating an image from an existing PNG file and seeing whether that displays correctly?

Comment: I tried. Calling `imagepng($im, "/full/path/to/file");` but the image was not even created.

Comment: I meant creating the PNG *from* an existing file, not *to* a file.